# A search on the already searched grid data

Tags: jqgrid

Suppose I have a grid with data in it and there is Find records option that is for searching records based on certain column data. The above works fine.
The second scenario would be I want to search record on the above grid data.

A search on the already searched grid data.

Is that possible? I am trying to implement it in jqgrid and I am not getting any idea.

Comment: You should post the code which you use. Do you use *local* search or searching on the server? Which options of Searching you use? Do you use for example `multipleSearch: true` or `multipleGroup: true` options? (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching#options))

Comment: I am searching on the server. I do not use multiple search options. I will post the code in an hour